# Проблема с получением JSON пакета в WCF сервисе

Tags: c#, json, post, wcf, content-type

господа, требуется помощь в ситуации.
У меня имеется WCF сервис, и он должен принимать JSON пакеты, POST запросом, с обязательно указанным Content-Type = application/json.
Вот интерфейс моего метода -

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/Authorization",
              Method = "POST",
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Stream PostAuthorization(Stream value);
```

Вот описание класса сервиса в Web.config

```
    <services>
  <service name="WcfWebService.Services.GetVisitOnlineService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfWebService.Contracts.IGetVisitOnlineService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="WebBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

С помощью Postman пробую отправить себе запросы.

Когда я указываю в настройках Body "Text" запрос срабатывает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что показывает Fiddler
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А если я явно указываю Content-Type в Postman
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То в ответ прилетает ошибка 400, Fiddler, вот что кажет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В VS в метод даже не заходит, отдебажить не могу.
Не понимаю, чего не хватает?(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема заключается в том, что в интерфейсе сервиса необходимо явно указать любой тип данных, кроме Stream, с помощью потока можно сделать сервис с универсальной формой приема данных, и ему не нужен явно указанный Content-Type.